# How to merge 2 result sets with opposite order in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

Mysql table constructure:

```
id    date
1     2014-12-01
2     2014-12-02
3     2014-12-03
4     2014-12-04
5     2014-12-05
6     2014-12-06
7     2014-12-07
```

first select:

```
select * from table where id in (1,2,3,4) order by data desc;
```

second select:

```
select * from table where id in (5,6,7) order by data asc;
```

I tried to use UNION between and failed. It seems the ORDER BY could be used only once.
After the merging, I'd like to use LIMIT OFFSET for pagination.

Expecting result would be:

```
id    date
4     2014-12-04
3     2014-12-03
2     2014-12-02
1     2014-12-01
5     2014-12-05
6     2014-12-06
7     2014-12-07
```

I'm using Laravel in my project. Its pagination is very easy. So I'd like to know how to implement it with Laravel Eloquent.

Comment: What should be the result of your query for your example?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. What I am expecting has been appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. **[Fiddler Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7eca9/7)**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
      select * from table where id in (1,2,3,4) order by data desc
) Test
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
(
      select * from table where id in (5,6,7) order by data asc
) Test2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it doesn't work, it gave me a hint. This seems right. SELECT * FROM (select * from table where id in (1,2,3,4) order by id asc ) AS TMP 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (select * from table where id in (5,6,7)  ORDER BY id desc) AS TMP2

Comment: @JasonW, if the query above returns the rows you need but they are not in the desired order you can append `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses to it (after `Test2`) to prepare the result set. In fact, if the order matters then you need to append it. MySQL states in the [documentation of `UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) that *"use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows"*.