# How to make a pagination from Eloquent Collection?

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 4.2.
This is my code.

```
$events = $this->eventService->paginateAllEvents(2,0); //array of stdClass
$array = [];
foreach($events as $event){
      $array[] = with(new Event())->newFromStd($event); //change stdClass to Eloquent Class
}
$events = new Collection($array); // get Collection to use its load method.
$events->load(['specialties', 'eventType']); // eager load the relationships.

$paginator = Paginator::make($events->toArray(), $totalCount, $perPage);
```

Here is my problem. item in the $paginator is array, not Object. So when I loop the $paginator, I cannot use $event->title. So I have to use $event['title'] now.

I want to have Object in the items of $paginator, just like what Event::paginate() does. Any help?

Comment: Is there a reason your EventService couldn't just use the Event model and built-in pagination? You're going through a lot of extra steps that will basically give you identical results.

Comment: @Cryode , because the the sql is too complicated for Eloquent Model to make.

Comment: The sql I am querying is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397798/how-to-merge-2-result-sets-with-opposite-order-in-mysql